# Why Pages can match the Navigator.push on flutter?

Tags: flutter

when I use navigator2.0 pages to control route.

then when I use Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DemoPage()));

that's works ok.

but I did not change the pages, I also find pages don't changed.

Why Pages can match the Navigator.push?

for example: pages only have one，then Navigator.push()，there are actually two routes ，but page.length has always been 1.

running effect is ok, pop can also work ok,everything looks ok, how is this done？

Thank you very much for your reply。

Comment: What language you're talking in, bro?

Comment: Why pages can match? ☹️what does that mean ?